# Using scroll bars for big plots in R Shiny app

Tags: r, plot, shiny, scrollbar, horizontal-scrolling

I would like to add a scrollbar for a plot in Shiny app, but only the vertical scroll bar appear while horizontal scroll bars do not appear. I attached a small shiny app with minimum elements here to demonstrate the problem.

```
cat("\014")
unlink(".RData")
rm(list=ls(all.names = TRUE))

  # A basic shiny app with a plotOutput
  shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
        ),
        mainPanel(
          column(6,(div(style='width:200px;overflow-x: scroll;height:200px;overflow-y: scroll;',
                      uiOutput("plot"))) )

        )
      )
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {
      output$plot <- renderUI({
       output$plot2 <- renderPlot(plot(cars))
       plotOutput('plot2')
      })
    }
  )
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default `renderPlot(width="auto")` causes it to inherit the width from the default `plotOutput(width="100%")`. This means the plot is drawn to the size of the div, which here you give to be 200px, therefore no overflow is required. Overflow will be active if you explicitly specify either the width of `renderPlot(width=300)` or of `plotOutput(width="300px")` (note the former is integer, latter is character).

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
      ),
      mainPanel(
        column(6,(div(style='width:200px;overflow-x: scroll;height:200px;overflow-y: scroll;',
                      uiOutput("plot"))) )
        
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$plot <- renderUI({
      output$plot2 <- renderPlot(plot(cars),width=300) # either will
      plotOutput('plot2',width='300px')                # work
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution fixed my problems.

Comment: @XiaoweiMa great! Could you please mark my solution as answered?

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/1639069/brooks-ambrose. Sorry , the website did not allow me to give you positive feedback: "Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: @XiaoweiMa You should see a check mark icon below the positive/negative feedback arrows that would allow you to accept Brooks answer as a solution. You don't need any reputation to do this.